# Word that means "Simultaneously relaxed and focused"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I saw George Will on TV and he used a word (and immediately defined it) but all I was heard was the definition, not the actual word.  "Emmetropic" is the closest I can come to finding a word that meets the definition "simultaneously relaxed and focused" but it seems to have such a specific, physical, meaning and the context seemed to me to indicate a mental state rather than a physical one.

Comment: Reminds me of 'grace under pressure'.

Answer (score 8):

Try [in the zone](http://www.wordnik.com/words/in%20the%20zone)

> adjective
>      1. In a mental state of focused concentration on the performance of an
>   activity, in which one dissociates
>   oneself from distracting or irrelevant
>   aspects of one's environment.

Here's [another definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/zone)

> a temporary state of heightened
>   concentration experienced by a
>   performing athlete that enables peak
>   performance  ***(i.e. players in the zone)***

Answer (score 7):

This is probably jargon, but "[flow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_%28psychology%29)" seems to describe what you mean.

> Don't interrupt him, he's in the flow.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds almost like he was talking about hypnosis.  I think the **hypnagogic** state is one in which you are both relaxed and focused.

But it also might have been one of my favorite words, **excogitation**, which means to ponder or think intently about something.  I love that word.

Answer (score 2):

The word was probably "intent".

> The man was intent on his work.

This implies a state of focus or deep involvement without stress or panic.

Less likely but still good alternatives might be "attentive", "earnest", "rapt", "preoccupied", "immersed", "engaged",  or "concentrated".

Answer (score 2):

[Zen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zen) is a word used to describe a relaxed and focused meditative state.

> I do my best work when I am in a state of Zen.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the word "collected".

Answer (score 2):

[Equipoise](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/equipoise)
He [uses it](https://youtu.be/GaOoQKBqSUk?t=2h7m20s) in the Ken Burns documentary Baseball when describing Jackie Robinson's entry into major league baseball.

Comment: This perfectly answers the question, although I think the other words were more generally usable. The link is now broken, though. [Here](https://wikipiebenga.org/?p=311)'s an article that talks about it.